# Does a method declared as `override` remain `virtual`?

Tags: c#

is a method declared with `override` still `virtual`?

For example

```
class C1 {

public virtual void MyMethod()
{
}

}

class C2: C1 {

public override void MyMethod()
{
}

}
```

Does `MyMethod` defined in `C2` remain `virtual` as the method defined in `C1` which it overrides? i.e. Can it be overridden by a method in a class derived from `C2`?

If not, how can I make it virtual?

Comment: Did you mean `class C2 : C1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can override it but once you `seal` it, then you can no longer override it if you derive from the sealed version:

```
public class C1 {

  public virtual void MyMethod() {
  }

}
public class C2 : C1 {
  public sealed override void MyMethod() {
     base.MyMethod();
  }
}
```

Below will not work:

```
public class C3 : C2 {
  // here you will no longer be able to override it
}
```

But if other classes derive `C1`, that will still work.

Comment: I had no idea you could seal _methods_. +1

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can continue to `override` it as many times as you need to in subsequent subclasses.

From the C# 5.0 spec (my emphasis):

> A virtual method can be overridden in a derived class. When an
>   instance method declaration includes an override modifier, the method
>   overrides an inherited virtual method with the same signature. Whereas
>   a virtual method declaration introduces a new method, *an override
>   method declaration specializes an existing inherited virtual method by
>   providing a new implementation of that method.*

Section 10.6.5 talks about what CodingYoshi is referring to, but it shows an example that it can be  done.

Comment: Thanks. The quote doesn't say that a method declared with `override` is `virtual` or not. Does the specification mention that somewhere?

Comment: Does the specification mention that somewhere?